# Swift 4.1 чтение и запись в поле Text View

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa, swift4

Пару дней как изучаю Swift 4, возникли трудности.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно программно читать и записывать данные с Text View. С Text Field ознакомился довольно быстро, и понял про `stringValue` и другие методы. А вот с Text Field и его `NSTextView`, что-то мучаюсь уже долго..

Задача: сделать multi-line текстовое поле с возможностью скроллинга и переноса строки по Enter. Как понимаю, подобное лучше сделать через `NSTextView` (Text Field). И теперь столкнулся с задачей, как же "читать" текст внутри поля и как записывать программно.

```
 @IBOutlet var fieldNoteMulti: NSTextView!
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему NSTextView а не UITextView ?

Comment: На сколько понимаю, UI* для iOS приложений а NS* для macOS. На данный момент изучаю именно под MacOS. Подправьте, если ошибаюсь.

Comment: Именно так, хотя скоро на macOS завезут и UIKit. А в чем именно проблема в чтении и записи?

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что не смог найти "родных" методов для данной манипуляции. В то время, как в NSTextField есть родной - stringValue.

На данный момент вопрос решил, все работает. Но хотелось бы понимать целесообразность моих действий. Так как важно не просто, чтобы работало, а чтобы было правильно изложено со стороны кода :)

Решил методом создания extension-а. Подробности прилагаю в ответе к данному вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем решении слишком много лишних действий.

Для установления новой строки в `NSTextView` можно сразу обращаться к свойству `string`:

```
textViewName.string = ""
```

Для чтения значения используйте то же самое свойство `string` напрямую (и без `description`, описание строки Вам ни к чему):

```
let getString = textViewName.string
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Оказалось все на такой поверхности.. Не посоветуете хорошую книгу или сайт для глубокого ознакомления с Swift 4 ?

Comment: @PerfectoWeb Сперва хотя бы внимательно прочитайте The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4.1) от Apple Inc.

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент решил вопрос созданием расширения, а точнее вот так:

```
extension NSTextView {
    var text: String! {
        get {
            return string
        }
        set {
            self.string = newValue
        }
    }  
}
```

Все работает отлично. Однако, хотелось бы знать наверняка актуальность и целесообразность такого подхода. Так как важнее понимать "как это работает" и как более грамотно оформить решение, нежели "работает, ну и черт с ним".

**Далее запись происходит так:**

```
textViewName.text = ""
```

**А чтение так:**

```
let getString = textViewName.text.description
```